# Is it provable that gravity can not emerge from the standard model?

Tags: gravity, standard-model, emergent-properties

This seems like a really foolish question, but is it provable that the standard model does not contain gravitation as some emergent phenomenon? There are obvious extensions to the SM as well, e.g. models with neutrino masses, that one might also be interested in considering.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergent_gravity

Comment: Hi @annav, yes I am aware there are QFTs that have emergent gravity, but I am not aware if we know which classes of QFTs admit GR and if the SM is part of that class

Comment: Provability assay request?

Answer (score 2):

The Standard Model contains particles of spin-0, 1/2, and 1, and so does not "natively" contain a graviton (spin-2).

The [Weinberg-Witten theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem) implies that a massless spin-2 particle cannot be composite in a Lorentz invariant quantum field theory. Therefore, it's not possible for the graviton to be a composite particle, made of other particles in the standard model.

Comment: I'm not sure why we would expect a graviton to emerge. Surely schemes like entropic gravity don't have gravitons?

Comment: @CasualScience Any quantum theory of gravity should look like an effective field theory of gravity with a graviton in the weak field limit. Or put another way, any viable theory of gravity needs to have a spin-2 field in an appropriate limit since we've observed gravitational waves.

Comment: @CasualScience I guess you might say that all that's needed for entropic gravity is to reproduce classical GR, not effective field theory of gravity. I would say that "gravity emerging from the standard model" to me, means that you just need the standard model and the usual rules of quantum field theory, to get something that looks like GR. If you have GR and the usual rules of QFT, you will get gravitons. If there's some other formulation that has the same SM fields but non-standard rules, I would still say that's beyond the SM. But it would be nice to see equations and not just words...

Comment: Yeah I think what you are saying is a totally legit way of thinking about it. But I think I'm asking something more general. For me to be satisfied, you'd have to show me that no new effects can emerge outside of the known E&M eqs at large scales using the standard model (not sure how one would show that).

Answer (score 0):

Kinda. The standard model doesn't include a metric and assumes from the start that it's Minkowski spacetime. There might be some attempts to extended SM which includes gravity, but I would say that this is when string theory kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is that gravity is not renormalizable (at high energies) due to self-interactions. At best, it's an effective field theory, rather than the renormalizable electroweak theory in the SM (proven by 't Hooft and Veltman).